# IE, textarea value is not changed when pressing buttons

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events

I have a really nasty problem with focus in Internet Explorer.

I have a textarea for inputting text. This textarea is not visible for the user and is only used to provide robust text input for a more advanced view.

As the textarea isn't visible and shouldn't be I use `textarea.focus()` in the JavaScript to activate text-input. This has worked fine until now where I get really weird results.

For the textinput I basically use this event plus an exact copy for onkeypress.

```
textarea.onkeyup = function (e) {
        //textarea.value contains the full text
        //Update the view with this value
};
```

The problem is that sometimes `textarea.value` is not updated. I can even see the button in `e.keyCode` on the `keyup` event above but the value isn't changed.
This seems to happen after I have clicked somewhere on the page, but this does not trigger a blur-event. I'm logging the onfocus- and onblur-events so I can see when the textarea loses focus but it doesn't. And i still receive the keyup/press/down events.

If I try to refocus the textarea with `textarea.focus()` the problem remains. A workaround I found though is to focus the window with `window.focus()` and right after call `textarea.focus()`.
The problem with this is that focus is a really expensive operation in IE (no kidding) and since I cannot detect when this problem will happen I have to keep doing it with certain interval which seriously affects the performance of my application (involves animation etc).

I use the exact same code for other browsers and do not have this problem there.

Comment: Not an answer, but if you find you have to give up on the textarea thing, this page may help with navigating the vagaries of keyboard events cross-browser: http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Answer (score 0):

Change the identifier to something less generic like "textAreaAdv", IE sometimes get confused with this word.

Comment: In my code it's actually called something different already but thanks for the advice.